# Как использовать DirectShow с MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, directshow

При компиляции MinGW ругается, что в dshow.h присутствуют не разрешённые заголовки. Например, он не может найти d3dtypes, ddraw, dsound. При ручном добавлении этих заголовков, компилятор выдаёт другие кучи ошибок.

Есть ли решение этой проблемы? Как работать с DirectShow в MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать конкретно MinGW-w64, у меня после этого перестал ругаться

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).